# How to Display a List of Post Titles Related to a Specific Topic

Tags: wordpress, list, post, blogs, title

All the posts I created will be listed in “Blog”, and I have a page called “China Business”.  How can I display a list of Post Titles related to “China Business”  on the China Business page, manually and automatically? And these posts should not be displayed on “Blog” any more. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom template. and in that template fetch all post title in this template. To fetch all post title you should use while loop like this.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: China Business
*/
<?php query_posts('cat=5'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

on top line use your blog category id in replace of "5" . Let me know if you have still any problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should use  the [in_category tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) to filter the posts output,

try something like:

```
    if( !in_category( 'China-Business' ))
```

for blog page

---

If for China business page you want to create a page with the posts in that category
look in to the [page-of-posts template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates),
otherwise (if you don't have any china-Business page content and just want a list of titles) use a customized archive template ([category.php for ex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)) .

EDIT:
Basically creating a Page-of posts puts together a page content with a WP_query,
in this way you'll be getting the page-content and also a list of posts (or related info) in the output;

in reference to Arshad's answer remember to be careful when using query_posts , it's recommended to use WP_query instead (like explained in the WP CODEX)

Comment: As Xiaojue Xu has already told that "china-business" is a page. then why are you giving answer as a category?

Comment: he is asking:"...how can I display a list of Post Titles related to “China Business” on the China Business page..."; and the way I explained he will automatically fetch posts in specific category (you need to know list of posts template to understand.. ); through some simple CSS he could output only titles - excerpts -or whatever related to the posts